# is it a good idea to store all data from database into the redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am building a asset management web application. I have seen in several tutorials that the data we call from APIs is stored in the redux store, for better UI performance. BUT would it be a good idea?
The data my application deals with is going to be in 1000s of records. This data will go in local-storage. Performance will be high no-doubt but security-wise will be the right thing to do?

Please guide, when to use and when not?

Guys, after reading the responses below... I gather the following understanding, please correct me if I am wrong.

- For large-scale and dynamic applications
  We can go for Redux Cautiously. The following types of activities can go in Redux....

  - The UI layout, dashboards, etc
  - Current Logged-in User, his Profile, etc
  - Key List of values
  - Key fields of your tables in database, but not all fields, clean store after a set time interval, by marking it old.

Is my above understand correct?

Comment: Is all that data shown on the page? You can do some kind of paging and use only subset of the data.

Comment: For the sake of memory and performance, it is not good idea to fetch and store whole data to client side. Fetch and show only necessary data. You can use pagination or something else.

Comment: @mstfyldz yes I agree... But many developers just consider that Redux is the best way... So wanted to ask this question and get clarification, our answers might help many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Storing all the data in the client side

**Pros**

1. Once the data is loaded, Page render will be faster

**Cons**

1. As your application grows your data will also grow, at one point it will be unsustainable
2. If your dataset is large (which will be most likely) it will take so long to fetch, and also as it grows you just cannot handle it in the UI
3. You might have data synchronous issue, since there is no pull from the backend you cannot make sure your data is valid

It depends upon your `application size` and the `volume of data` you want to handle. If your application has only one or two source of data, data size is less than `100` and there is `no transactions` you can go for it, but not for a application which will need to be dealt with huge data sets.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a big problem handling those records in redux, what I advise you for performance is that, instead of asking your API for all records, implement something that can give you X records, e.g. for paginated tables where big data is fetched on each page, the user and the redux will only have about 3 pages of 25 records,and you can clean old ones if you see that this amount of data is slowing you down, having this, your browser's page will not take ages to load because it's not waiting on big data response from the server, instead it will fetch small amounts.

When I say paginated it can be a scroll with loading that fetches data when it reaches the end...